# Cannot use Record<keyof T, string> as index to a dictionary in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I have the following interface:

```
interface Car {
    color?: string;
    model?: string;
}
```

I want to create a method that receives a key of that dictionary and retrieves the value:

```
function retrieveValue(car: Car, key: Record<keyof Car, string>) {
    return car[key];
}
```

It fails on the `return` line:

> Type 'Record<"color" | "model", string>' cannot be used as an index type.ts(2538)

It is not very intuitive for me to understand where my mistake is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use the `Record<...>` syntax. Instead, you can simply use this:

```
function retrieveValue(car: Car, key: keyof Car) {
    return car[key];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for `keyof` not `Record`.

```
function retrieveValue(car: Car, key: keyof Car) {
    return car[key];
}
```

`Record` does [something else](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeystype).